# SSRS rdl file, trying to add html tag in a column and render it as HTML

Tags: reporting-services

I have below text in one of the output columns of stored procedure:

> Exterior-<a>http://abc/KB05ZZG_DefaultCustomBackground-003_Exterior_20180906114840.jpg</a&gt;
>   Front
>   Left-<a>http://abc/KB05ZZG_DefaultCustomBackground-003_FrontLeft_20180906114842.jpg</a&gt;
>   Front-<a>http://abc/KB05ZZG_DefaultCustomBackground-003_Front_20180906114844.jpg</a&gt;
>   Back
>   Right-<a>http://abc/KB05ZZG_DefaultCustomBackground-003_BackRight_20180906114846.jpg</a&gt;
>   Back-<a>http://abc/KB05ZZG_DefaultCustomBackground-003_Back_20180906114848.jpg</a&gt;
>   Back
>   Left-<a>http://abc/KB05ZZG_DefaultCustomBackground-003_BackLeft_20180906114851.jpg</a&gt;

This sp is used in RDL file and we want make the image links clickable. I know how this can be done in crystal reports but I am trying to achieve the same in visual studio.
Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time today morning found a solution for this and there are several steps to achieve it:
1. Changed the select query in my SP to : 
SELECT visi.[Caption] + '-' + ''+ iu.[URL] +'' + ' '

2. Database returns < and > for < and > signs respectively and report viewer shows it as  tag in preview but still as plain text.
3. Added below expression to evaluate.
   =Replace(Replace(Fields!BgImag.Value, "<", "<"), ">", ">")
   This actually replaces characters in the data.
4. Last but not the least changed in the Placeholder Properties, General tab: set Markup type as Html.

All sorted now !!!